# Jane's often visited the museums before

Tags: present-perfect, adverbs

What's the difference between these two sentences? Are "in the past" and "before" used interchangeably?

> Jane's often visited the museums in the past.

> Jane's often visited the museums before.

There are two possible contexts: 1. But she doesn't anymore. 2. Tomorrow, she's going to visit a newly opened museum, the beds' museum.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct. They don't imply anything about the future, so either of your "two possible contexts" might be true.

Both sentences are fine if you want to emphasize "in the past" or "before". Otherwise, those phrases are redundant (because the verb is in the present perfect), and it would be more common to say something like:

> Jane has often visited the museums.

Comment: "Jane's often visited museums before, but tomorrow she's going to a new one." (No article needed, because it means 'museums in general'.)

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, if that's the intended meaning.